# Error executing cmd to get Android AVD's list from java program running on Windows

Tags: java, android

Im trying to get the list of installed AVD's in my machine by executing:

```
try {

    String exeCmd = sdkPath + "/tools/bin/avdmanager list avd";

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(exeCmd);
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After running this code I read the input and see if I have emulators to start.

This piece of code runs fine when executing the program on a Mac but throws an `IOException` when I run it on Windows, like so:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified (...)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:444)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:139)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 7 more
```

Can someone help me resolve this problem or point me to a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome Fernando.

The code is using both Windows and Unix directory style, hence you end up with a Windows path like so: `"C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager"`

You see both the `\` and the `/`. Since your Mac is unix based, `sdkPath` will resolve to a path with `/` separators.

To make your code portable (for Unix based OS or not), use `File.separator` instead of `/`. That way, the JVM will produce the correct separator based on the underlying OS.

```
try {

    String exeCmd = sdkPath + File.separator + "tools" + File.separator "bin" + File.separator + "avdmanager list avd";

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(exeCmd);
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can improve this by making it prettier using a different API to generate the path, but at least you get the gist of it.

Comment: I tried your aproach but i still get the same error, could it be because of the spaces in "avdmanager list avd"?

Comment: interesting! What happens if you try to put this in your Windows explorer: `"C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/tools/bin/"`? Does it find it find the folder?

Comment: Where do you run it? 
Also, what if you use this in the explorer: `C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin`

Comment: Yes it finds the foder and inside we have the "avdmanager" batch file.

Comment: ok, I see. The folder "/" vs "\" does matter. Now, what is the extension of `avdmanager`?

Comment: It's a batch file (.bat)

Comment: I think I know why now. Can you print the environment variable `PATHEXT`?

Comment: Yes i can. I get this value, PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

Comment: what happens if you add `.bat` to the answer I gave ("avdmanager.bat")? Moreover, how do you start this app? Something is whipping your `PATHEXT`

Comment: Ok so by adding the extension to the cmd string it now works. Thanks a lot for your time and patience.